# how to check if splunk has received the logs from 100 different hosts

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula

I am new to splunk. Wanted to create a splunk alert to check if logs has been received from all the host or not and if not need to set a alert trigger.

```
| tstats latest(_time) as latest where index=* earliest=-24h by host
| eval recent = if(latest > relative_time(now(),"-5m"),1,0), realLatest = strftime(latest,"%c")
| where recent=0
```

is the above splunk Query correct?

Answer (score 1):

The query looks good, but the best way to know is to try it.  Does it produce the desired results?